# How to send real JSON object to server with quotation?

Tags: javascript, json, laravel-5.1, restangular

I have a variable like this:

```
$scope.task.gallery=[ 
       {"name": "XCB808tvXNpqXKqekA2HlkJ8H.jpg","size":5112}, 
       {"name": "s6kA6B0e5m1sdSAjPXqNwtiy4.jpg", "size": 13135} 
];
```

But when get this in server, show me object without quotation:

```
[ 
     {name: "XCB808tvXNpqXKqekA2HlkJ8H.jpg",size:5112}, 
     {name: "s6kA6B0e5m1sdSAjPXqNwtiy4.jpg", size: 13135} 
];
```

I use php Laravel 5.1 for backend in server. when I send with `Restangular` and use `json_decode` send me error `json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given`.

I think `Restangular` change variable and then send. how to send array object JSON as real ?

Comment: Try `JSON.stringify($scope.task.gallery)` before sending to server

Comment: I am trying but doesn't work